# How to select mesh faster in edit mode with blender 2.93?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, selection-tools, select

H i everyone , I was just struggling with selection speed in blender 2.93 it was too much frustrating  , and i was wondering is this possible to increase the speed of selection?
or is this possible to select heavy meshes faster in blender ?

Answer (score -1):

and YES ! i found a solution and that is "alt shift z" , and even deselecting is affected by this and i guess this is a bug (*and i don't have opportunity to report it if someone can*)
I hope someone find this helpful .

[image]

Just a simple update to better understood how it works , here is another test gif :
[image]

Comment: I am totally confused about what you needed and what you found in your answer, Alt shift Z disables overlays of your scene, how is it affecting selection?

Comment: @MikoCG I don't understand it either... well, he's talking about "heavy" meshes, so of course this might slow down the viewport and also slow down selecting mesh parts. I've experienced that as well but didn't have the impression that it was worse in 2.93 than in previous versions. And maybe disabling overlays might speed this up because Blender has less to display...? But I tried it and actually don't see any significant speed difference between 2.83.5 and 2.93.5, and disabling overlays doesn't help - it makes things worse, because now I can't see what I selected anymore.

Comment: Sorry @hamed.design - if this works for you, that's fine. But I don't think this will really help anybody else. I've tried it now on a really heavy mesh and my viewport was very slow. Moving across the mesh with Circle select only selected a few parts of it. After disabling overlays, the viewport was still slow, and Circle select again only selected very few parts of it. And you can't see what is selected because there are no overlays so this is absolutely useless to make specific selections.

Comment: @MikoCG i was just figure this out (I tested it on that gif file) idk what are those down votes for ? i just thought this might be helpful for someone who use heavy meshes ( selecting a part of a mesh by pressing L and remove it)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann maybe youre out of ram how much heavy your mesh is dude ? for me as it shown on that gif file it has a significant change , maybe you can't notice it , or youre trying to be offensive about someone sharing his experience , but give it another try it should work , also if you want to see what youre selecting just pre alt shift z back :)

Comment: I don't know how aggressive you are in general, I never post anything just to be offensive. I'm far from being out of RAM, I made an extra high-poly mesh to test it. And as I said the same mesh didn't make any significant difference on 2.83 or 2.93, so it might be a bug but I don't think it's a general version problem either. And I'm sorry, but if I want to select specific parts of a complex mesh it's simply not very comfortable if I have to switch back and forth between overlayed and not overlayed.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann me too , and im pretty agreed with what you said in comments , but may you please record your screen for us to compare the speed between two methods ? since i said faster , and never said fastest , and if it changes the speed that means i found something and those dislikes are unfair ( also checkout for new update ctrl t works even faster without overlays , im recording screen for that )

Comment: I'm sorry I'm at work and don't have time to do anything to prove to you what I experience here. The simple truth is, it's not working good enough (no noticeable speed change, still missing vertices in selection) to make up for the uncomfortable fact that I can't see what I'm doing. This is why I don't see it as a good answer for general usability. If you see it differently, that's fine. I never asked you to remove your answer.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann My dear friend , even deselecting is faster and it worth presing alt shif z , if you wanted to select thru you should press alt z , also i tried move my mouce as fast as possible but no verticies remain unselected .

Comment: **1.** It may be faster on your pc, but not mine and maybe not someone else's. **2.** I say it's not helping selecting specific areas in complex meshes, I don't mean simple selecting from left to right but exactly faces/vertices I need to select. **3.** I didn't talk about backside vertices, using Blender for 8 years I know what x-ray mode is. **4.** Stop trying to convince me it must be the same on my computer because it works on yours. I just wanted to share that I can't reproduce the result, you're trying to force me to believe it must be the same on my machine. I'm out of this discussion.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oh my ... im so sorry to disappointed you mate ,  im not the dev of blender, it might be a specific case of yours , i guess i can halp ? also i added a new gif watch it out